# Composite component listner inputtext value

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, composite-component

I have an XHTML page which describes the following user composite component

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
      xmlns:ui_component="http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite/ui_component" >
    <h:body>
         <h:form id="mergeform">          
                    <p:separator/>
                    <p:panelGrid styleClass="tableEdit" style="width: 100%">
                        <f:facet name="header">
                            <p:row>    
                                <p:column colspan="2">  
                                    <h:outputLabel style="font-size: 20px;" value="1-ое застрахованное лицо" />    
                                </p:column>
                                <p:column style="text-align: right; width: 20em;">
                                    <p:commandButton style="font-size: 14px;" value="Общий поиск" immediate="true" 
                                                     onclick="dialogPersonList.show();document.getElementById('mergeform:personNumber').value = '1';dlg22Search.show();" 
                                                     action="#{mergeBean.updateListPerson}"
                                                     oncomplete="dlg22Search.hide();"
                                                     update=":mergeform:enpsearchtable mergeform:checkSearch"/>
                                </p:column> 
                            </p:row> 
                        </f:facet>                  
                        <p:row>    
                            <p:column colspan="3">
                                <ui_component:personTable id="First" form="mergeform" id_link="Second" bean="#{mergeBean}" val="#{mergeBean.merge}" smoChanger="true" >
                                    <f:validator validatorId="FIOValidator" for="FIOValid" />                               
                                </ui_component:personTable>                            
                          </p:column> 
                        </p:row> 
                    </p:panelGrid>
                    <p:panelGrid styleClass="tableEdit" style="width: 100%">
                        <f:facet name="header">
                            <p:row>    
                                <p:column colspan="2">  
                                    <h:outputLabel style="font-size: 20px;" value="2-ое застрахованное лицо" />  
                                </p:column>
                                <p:column style="text-align: right; width: 20em;">
                                    <p:commandButton style="font-size: 14px;" value="Общий поиск" immediate="true" 
                                                     onclick="dialogPersonList.show();document.getElementById('mergeform:personNumber').value = '2';dlg22Search.show();"
                                                     action="#{mergeBean.updateListPerson}" 
                                                     oncomplete="dlg22Search.hide();"
                                                     update=":mergeform:enpsearchtable mergeform:checkSearch" />
                                </p:column> 
                            </p:row> 
                        </f:facet>
                        <p:row>    
                            <p:column colspan="3">  
                                <ui_component:personTable id="Second" bean="#{mergeBean}" val="#{mergeBean.merge.inputData}" smoChanger="true" >
                                    <f:validator validatorId="FIOValidator" for="FIOValid" />  
                                </ui_component:personTable>
                            </p:column> 
                        </p:row> 
                    </p:panelGrid>
         </h:form>        
    </h:body>
</html>
```

Component itself is a panelGrid with multiple row. For example, I led the line where the problem occurs. Description validators I also lowered.

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:cc="http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"  
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets">

    <cc:interface>
        <cc:attribute name="id" />
        <cc:attribute name="bean" />
        <cc:attribute name="val" />
        <cc:attribute name="id_link" />
        <cc:attribute name="form" />
        <cc:attribute name="readonly" default="false" />
        <cc:attribute name="smoChanger" default="false" />
        <cc:editableValueHolder name="FIOValid" targets="Secondname#{cc.attrs.id}" />
        <cc:editableValueHolder name="DocValid" targets="DocNum#{cc.attrs.id}" />
        <cc:editableValueHolder name="PolValid" targets="PolNum#{cc.attrs.id}" />
        <cc:editableValueHolder name="PlaceBirthValid" targets="PlaceBirth#{cc.attrs.id}" />
        <cc:editableValueHolder name="EnpValid" targets="Enp#{cc.attrs.id}" />  
        <cc:editableValueHolder name="OgrnValid" targets="Ogrn#{cc.attrs.id}" />  
    </cc:interface>

    <cc:implementation>
        <p:panelGrid id="#{cc.attrs.id}Person" style="font-size: 14px; width: 100%" styleClass="tableEdit" >                                                  
            <p:row>    
                <p:column style="width: 180px">  
                    <h:outputLabel for="Secondname#{cc.attrs.id}" value="Фамилия: " />
                </p:column>
                <p:column>
                    <p:inputText id="Secondname#{cc.attrs.id}" value="#{cc.attrs.val.secondname}" 
                                 readonly="#{cc.attrs.readonly}" >    
                        <p:ajax event="blur" process="@this" update="Secondname#{cc.attrs.id} ErrorsSecondname#{cc.attrs.id}" /> 
                        <p:ajax event="blur" listener="#{cc.attrs.bean.changeField}"
                                update="Secondname#{cc.attrs.id} ErrorsSecondname#{cc.attrs.id} 
                                :#{cc.attrs.form}:#{cc.attrs.id_link}:Secondname#{cc.attrs.id_link} 
                                :#{cc.attrs.form}:#{cc.attrs.id_link}:ErrorsSecondname#{cc.attrs.id_link}"
                                disabled="#{empty cc.attrs.id_link}" />
                    </p:inputText>
                </p:column>
                <p:column>
                    <h:message showSummary="false" showDetail="true"
                               style="color: red; font-size: 15px; 
                               text-decoration: underline;"
                               id="ErrorsSecondname#{cc.attrs.id}"
                               for="Secondname#{cc.attrs.id}"/> 
                </p:column>
            </p:row>       
        </p:panelGrid>  
    </cc:implementation>
</html>
```

In the bean MergeBean, I describe the listener, which is just an error occurs.

```
@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class MergeBean implements Serializable {

    private Person selectedPerson;

    public MergeBean() {
    }

    public Message getMerge() {
        if (this.merge == null) {
            this.merge = new Message();
            this.merge.setInputData(new Message());
        }
        return this.merge;
    }

    public void setMerge(Message merge) {
        this.merge = merge;
    }

    public void changeField(AjaxBehaviorEvent event) {
        String id = event.getComponent().getId();
        String valStr = ((HtmlInputText) event.getComponent()).getValue().toString();
        if (valStr != null && !valStr.isEmpty()) {
            String idChange = id.substring(0, id.length() - 5);
            UIInput input = (UIInput) UtilsUIXhtml.findComponent(idChange + "Second");
            //TODO
            Object objTemp = input.getSubmittedValue();
            //String tempStr = objTemp.toString();
            String cngStr = input.getValue().toString();
            if (cngStr == null || cngStr.isEmpty()) {
                input.setValue(valStr);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I'm trying to bind to the first text input in the first custom component and the method to find the associated text input in the second custom component and check its value to empty and null. But when I insert a row in pery input, the second input into the debugger input.getValue (). ToString () is equal to the value that the user entered, and not the fact that it really is. Why is this happening and how can I get the real value programmatly in the listener?

PS And so I'm looking for the components in the DOM-tree:

```
 public static UIComponent findComponent(final String id) {
    FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    UIViewRoot root = context.getViewRoot();
    final UIComponent[] found = new UIComponent[1];

    root.visitTree(new FullVisitContext(context), new VisitCallback() {
        @Override
        public VisitResult visit(VisitContext context, UIComponent component) {
            if (component.getId().equals(id)) {
                found[0] = component;
                return VisitResult.COMPLETE;
            }
            return VisitResult.ACCEPT;
        }
    });

    return found[0];
}
```